# "Error: no such file or directory" even when the command works file outside an script

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, grep, podman

I am writing an script that runs the command:

```
podman ps | grep -i healthy | grep netbackup | awk '{print $1}'
```

This commands works fine from the shell. However, it fails with "Error: no such file or directory" if I try to run it from a bash script.

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

```
[root@rservername tmp]# podman ps | grep -i healthy | grep netbackup | awk '{print $1}'
fc6725135e92
5bf17ae3b877
e1407dde3064
2ad1e55e8779
[root@rservername tmp]#

[root@rservername tmp]# ./test.sh
+ echo test
test
+ podman ps
+ grep -i healthy
+ grep netbackup
+ awk '{print $1}'
Error: no such file or directory

[root@rservername tmp]# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -x
echo "test"
podman ps | grep -i healthy | grep netbackup | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: I forgot to clarify that I am running this in RHEL8.6

[root@rservername  tmp]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
[root@rservername  tmp]#

Comment: More needed is an example of `podman ps`.   
Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try this: `sed -e "s|podman|$(which podman)|" -i test.sh`, then re-run your `test.sh`!

Comment: Check my edited answer for 'not found' error

Comment: `podman` seems to produce this error. It is probably a different environment that runs in the script. Running with `--log-level=debug` may produce more insights

Comment: You never need grep when ypu're using awk. `grep -i healthy | grep netbackup | awk '{print $1}'` = `awk '(tolower($0) ~ /healthy/) && /netbackup/ { print $1 }'` but there's probably a better way to do that if you show us the output of `podman` that you're processing.

Comment: Try changing your shebang from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` so you find the version of `bash` that's first in your `PATH` rather than the version that's in `/usr/bin` which may not be the same as the one you're using.

Answer (score 1):

For the `not found error`, add as second line of your script:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

to set PATH variable. Or define it explicitely, like:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

For the rest, What I would do, only one pipe:

```
podman ps | awk '$NF=="healthy" && $2=="netbackup"{print $1}'
```

---

Or to treat the output, better use [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) to parse the `JSON` that you could produce using:

```
podman ps --format json
```

If you show me the raw output of this command, I can help if you are not familiar with `jq`.

Comment: You can also leave the existing path but add elements of higher or lower priority: `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` (etc). You might also just `echo $PATH` on the CLI and in the script and compare them.